# What are the options to bulk/batch load data into Apache Geode(Gemfire)?

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, geode

We need to load millions of key/values into Apache Geode and we'd like to know what are some the options available. Our values happen to be in the 256kb range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options depending on your application requirements/SLAs or whether you need to perform conversion or other transformations, etc.

1. Out-of-the-box, Apache Geode provides the [Cache & Region Snapshot Service](http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/12/managing/cache_snapshots/chapter_overview.html).  This is useful when you want to migrate data from 1 existing Apache Geode cluster to another, for instance.  Not so useful if your data is coming from an external source, like a RDBMS.
2. Another option is to lazily load the data based on need.  This can be accomplished by implementing the [`CacheLoader` interface](http://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/CacheLoader.html) and [registering](http://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/RegionFactory.html#setCacheLoader-org.apache.geode.cache.CacheLoader-) the `CacheLoader` with a Region.  Obviously, you could create a `CacheLoader` implementation that intelligently loads a block of data based on some rules/criteria in addition to loading and returning the single value of interests based on the current requests.
3. A lot of times, users create an external, custom Conversion process or tool to extract, transform and bulk load (ETL) a bunch of data into Apache Geode.  This is typical in complex Use Cases or requirements.  However, it is highly advisable to use perhaps a framework/tool like...
4. [*Spring XD*](http://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/) (now [*Spring Cloud Data Flow*](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/) on *Pivotal's Cloud Foundry* (PCF)) is great ETL tool and pipeline for creating stream-based applications.  Spring XD / SCDF provides many different options for "[*sources*](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#sources)" and "[*sinks*](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#sinks)" (e.g. [GemFire Server](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#gemfire-server)).  In addition to *sources* & *sinks*, you can even "tap" the stream to process the data with "[*Processors*](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#processors)".  So whether you are doing real-time stream or batch-oriented data operations (e.g. bulk loads), *Spring XD* is a great option.
5. I am sure Google might provide other answers on how to perform ETL with a KeyValue store like Apache Geode.

Hope this helps get you going.

Cheers,
John

Answer (score 1):

We have very limited options to load Gemfire regions .

1) Spring batch:

- Create Gemfire writer for load data and remove data
- Create batch configuration and lod it

2) Apache Spark

- https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/fast-data-access-using-gemfire-apache-spark-part-vaquar-khan-/